# How can i make this code more time efficient?

Tags: performance, matlab, time, for-loop

This is a part of the Profiler report, and shows how these lines are eating up the time. Can it be improved upon?

```
         434 %clean up empty cells in subPoly
         228  435 if ~isempty(subPoly) 
         169  436     subPoly(cellfun(@isempty,subPoly)) = []; 
              437 
              438     %remove determined subpoly points from the hull polygon
         169  439     removeIndex = zeros(size(extendedPoly,1),1); 
         169  440     for i=1:length(subPoly) 
         376  441         for j=1:size(subPoly{i}(:,1)) 
       20515  442             for k=1:size(extendedPoly,1) 
6.12 5644644  443                 if extendedPoly(k,:)==subPoly{i}(j,:) 
       30647  444                     removeIndex(k,1)=1; 
       30647  445                 end 
1.08 5644644  446             end 
0.02   20515  447         end 
         376  448     end 
         169  449     extendedPoly = extendedPoly(~removeIndex(:,1),:);  
         169  450 end
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of what this code does?

Comment: Depending on whether a match is likely or unlikely, you might get a large gain by reordering the loops so that k is on the outside.  Then, for the first match of any of i/j against k, you can set removeIndex, then break out of the remainder of i/j (early exit).

Comment: Hmm.  Vector `==` is strange in this context.  Do you mean that the entire row has to be numerically equal?  Then make this explicit with `all(somerow == someotherrow)`.  Also look out for rounding issues associated with floating point representation.  Consider some distance measure with a threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Matlab has a tendency to think that everything on the command line is an array of doubles, and assuming that the contents of your arrays and cell arrays are numbers, you can replace

```
         if extendedPoly(k,:)==subPoly{i}(j,:) 
             removeIndex(k,1)=1; 
         end
```

with the equivalent

```
removeIndex(k,1) = extendedPoly(k,:)==subPoly{i}(j,:)
```

which might save a few nano-seconds, though I'll be a bit surprised if it saves much more.

I suspect that if I was a little smarter or more diligent I could probably replace your entire loop nest with a single assignment along the lines of

```
removeIndex = extendedPoly==subPoly
```

The trick here is to ensure that all the arrays in the expression have the same dimensions.

Comment: `removeIndex(k,1)=1;`, but what u wrote copies the value of extendedPoly and subpoly, wherever they are equal..instead i want it to be 1.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably approaching a performance limit within the current nesting strategy.  The "slow" line only requires 1 usec per execution.

Generally in a set-matching case like this, you are better off sorting both sets, and then performing a single loop through both sets concurrently.  (Google "insertion sort" for more on this, also see this related question/answer [Optimization of timestamp filter in MATLAB - Working with very large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12381377/931379))

It's not immediately obvious how to best apply this to your circumstance.  If you post an executable example we could look into this more closely.

Without looking at executable code, it may make sense to expand your subPoly cell of vectors into a single, sorted numeric array (called something like `sortedElementsToremove`).  Then get the sort order from `extendedPoly` like this: `[~, ixsSortExpended] = sort(extendedPoly);`.

Now you can use a single loop with two indexes to perform the masking.  Something like this (code not tested):

```
ixExtended = 1;  %Index though sort order
for ixSub = 1:length(sortedElementsToremove);
    %Use while to update second index
    while ...
            (extendedPoly(ixsSortExpended(ixExtended))  < sortedElementsToremove(ixSub) ) && ...
            ixExtended < length(ixsSortExpended)
        ixExtended = ixExtended + 1;
    end
    if (sortedElementsToremove(ixSub) == extendedPoly(ixsSortExpended(ixExtended)))
        removeIndex(ixsSortExpended(ixExtended)) = true;
    end
end
```